# Will Netflix still function properly on my LG K7 if I root it?

Tags: root-access, backup, stock-android, hardware, lg

I recently got a new phone (LG K7, MetroPCS) and there are some things that I wanted to do, which require root access.

I know how to root, and I know some apps won't work on a rooted device (Android Pay, Samsung Pay, etc.) But on howtogeek.com it also said that some paid TV/video streaming services will not work.

I would like to know if this applies to Netflix, if it does, I probably won't root it, as I would like to continue using Netflix. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was using Netflix app on rooted device without problems, abouth month ago. So you probably won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You will still be able to view downloaded content, it only affects streaming (Netflix error 0013). Don't do those tricks you find on sites, it is useless to rename libs etc.

The only solution to get another build of Netflix - get them from Netflix, not other sites. You must permit installation of APKs from untrusted sources to do this. You will have to experiment with different builds, unless you find a page where someone with your exact phone type writes which build to get (from Netflix, nowhere else).